# ASP.NET MVC - check Facebook login status

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-login

This is more of a design question.

I figured out how to use the facebook login via the Facebook SDK c#.

**QUESTION: What is the best way to check whether the user is logged into FB or not each time the user goes to a different page?**

Back on ASP.NET webforms, I could simply put in code to check FB login status in the code behind of a master page. This was good ... once and done. But I don't understand how to implement something similar in Asp.Net MVC 4.0.

Given that the _Layout.cshtml file (which acts like a master page) is only a view (hence, no code behind), what is the best way to code a way to check if the user is logged into FB each time a user goes to a different web page? Because I would think, adding this bit of code to each controller can't be the optimal design solution.

The only solution that I can think of involves using Javascript on the client side to do a WebApi call ... I guess the script will be bundled with all the other scripts so that it runs on each page. But I was hoping to find a solution on the server side ...

I'm pretty new to MVC, learning things as I go along ... tips appreciated ... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of points that might help you devise a solution.

1. You *can* put code in your _Layout, but I agree that you want to be careful about doing so. You could create a helper or partial view and have your _Layout call it so that it's executed for every action. Your helper/partial would need to execute the required logic and then return something. The problem that I have with this is it's a lot of overhead every request.
2. You could do an AJAX call after the page is loaded (as you suggested). This means that the page still loads quickly. The problem I have with this is that you're now dependant on Javascript. It's also potentially a little hacky(?)
3. What about storing the user's status (logged on/off) in a session/cookie and also providing a 5 minute expiry. You can use the Helper/Partial method from before or have some logic fire in OnActionExecuting (or similar). Your logic should check to see if the status has expired and then connect to the Facebook API to update the status. This has the advantage of low overhead (i.e. not checking again until 5 minutes has passed).

I don't know of your exact situation so I can't say what method, if any, is best.

Comment: thanks very much for the tips. This requires some thinking ... I'll try to tackle this next weekend when I get more time (it's a side hobby project) ... will post back with anything meaningful ... cheers bud!

Comment: All good suggestions @Rowan. I think the answer may be found by using an Action Filter. I can create a global filter that applies to all controllers/methods. I just read the chp on filters this weekend. Hopefully, I can figure something out soon ... will post back once I get things sorted out. Thanks!